# UIPanGestureRecognizer resets position after navigating

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIView that can be translated along the X-axis. Everything works great but I noticed that if I navigate to another page and back, the new view position is lost and reset to how it's configured in the xib.

In iOS8, it actually works exactly as I would want; the view persists its last position. However in iOS7, this doesn't appear to be true so I'm guessing Apple fixed it in their latest os? Is there a workaround anyone knows of that can get this to work in iOS 7?

Comment: Can you simply store the position and restore it using `-viewDidDisappear` and `-viewWillAppear`?

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the last location and when you pop up your controller set the view's x-axis to this stored location

Comment: I've tried that but it's not working. Maybe my issue is I can't move this view at all? I just tried a simple test in viewWillAppear to simply move my view somewhere but it's not budging. Should setting it's frame origin not be suffice?

Comment: the issue is that the view is getting reset, Have you re-initialized your controller from any other view...try setting the stored value in viewwillAppear method

Comment: it does look like it's getting reset. I tested setting the x-origin in viewWillAppear and it set properly. However in viewWillDisappear it's back to the original value. What do you mean re-initializing it? All I'm doing is navigating to this page (viewWillAppear only gets called once). Can something else be resetting it perhaps? Again in iOS8 this does not occur.

Comment: can you share some code as in how you are navigating from this pafe and back

Comment: yes, I'll do it now. FYI if I set the origin in viewDidLayoutSubviews then it works but then you can see the view jump to that position after the viewcontroller animates into place.

Comment: `MyVC *myPage = [MyVC new];`
`[navController pushViewController:myPage animated:true];`

Comment: this myPAge is the second controller right from where you comback to the main view ??...plz add the code of you poping back to the main controller of containing the view

Comment: This is how I navigate to the page where my issue is. I use the same code to navigate away (but to a diff page obviously). That next page has the "back button" as a navigation item so I'm not doing anything there to come back to this page.

Comment: I just noticed that as soon as I start animating away to the next page, my view position gets reset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57784/discussion-between-geet-and-oren).